# freeTDS: Missing libtdsodbc.so file on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, freetds

I am trying to connect to a SQL server from a python script on a Mac OSX and after installing freeTDS using `brew install freeTDS` I can't seem to find the driver "`libtdsodbc.so`" anywhere on my machine so that I can place it in the connection string.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem or knows why it's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24550 for people with similar issues. There's more than one "fix" floated there.

Comment: yeah I found that a couple of mins after posting the question. I'll put the fix as an answer for anyone else who has the problem and reference the source.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So according to [This thread here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24550) the issue is with the way freeTDS is built now, you need to use `brew install freetds --with-unixodbc` and I can verify this fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - saved me a lot of trouble

Comment: This helped me move forward! Thank you. Now on to the next problem.

Comment: This is currently hanging for us - the download fails.